# Celery Flower UNAUTHENTICATED_API not working

Tags: docker-compose, celery, flower

I am working on a project using celery workers and Flower to monitor those workers. Both the worker and Flower are running as images inside one container. I want to change attributes of the worker using Flower, but trying to change values via the Flower web UI invokes the following error: `FLOWER_UNAUTHENTICATED_API environment variable is required to enable API without authentication`

I am starting the worker with `celery -A app.celery.celery_worker.celery worker --loglevel=info` and Flower with `celery -A app.celery.celery_worker.celery flower --port=${PORT} --conf=app/celery/flowerconfig.py`

I tried to set up a flowerconfig file with `FLOWER_UNAUTHENTICATED_API = True` at the path specified in the celery flower command. Still, when using the web UI of Flower to change values, the same error message pops up and Flower outputs `401 POST /api/worker/pool/grow/celery@615b8e2b9e60 (172.18.0.1): FLOWER_UNAUTHENTICATED_API environment variable is required to enable API without authentication`